# Check database table count in a Service

Tags: php, android, service

I would like to create a service that it just executes a php file in server in order to retrieve a table data count/number of records. 
`$query = "SELECT COUNT(id_person) FROM user_details";`
Normally, I'm using an `AsyncTask`class to execute a php file in server (ProgressDialog, etc...) and that's working perfectly. However, i'd like to make that check in a Service, so that if the count has changed i trigger a notification. Any idea please of how making that ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger a broadcast from your service, and then implement a BroadCastReceiver that does the processing.

```
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction(ServiceResponseReceiver.ACTION_CHANGED);
    broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
```

Then

```
public class ServiceResponseReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String ACTION_CHANGED = "your.package.SOMETHING_CHANGED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (ACTION_CHANGED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                          // Do processing here, trigger notification or anything
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So the AsyncTask that checks for table count will be done in the BroadcastReceiver ? Service is useless in that case, no? I just can create BroadcastReceiver and make the treatement inside of it.

Comment: No, I meant you check the database table in `Service`. Then if the count has changed, you send a broadcast. Then you show notification or do whatever you want in the `BroadcastReceiver`.